# What's a natural way to say "let's stay here" in Japanese?

Tags: expressions

While doing an exercise on the uses of 一応, I realized I am not sure how to say "Let's stay at home" in a natural way. This is the exercise:

> 「一応」を使って文を完成させなさい。
>
> 天気予報で今日は雨は降らないと言っていたが、雲が少し出てきたので、___________________
>
> According to the weather forecast it will not rain today, but it got a little cloudy, so ___________________

I attempted to complete the sentence by adding "let's stay at home just in case", where the "just in case" part is the mandatory 一応, but I am unsure of how to say let's stay at home part. I am thinking of:

- 一応家に留まろう。
- 一応家に居よう。

But I am not sure if this is the proper nor the more natural way to express it. In particular, the second option 家に居よう sounds horrible to me, but I can't tell if it's valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be 家にいよう. It's the volitional from of いる and there is nothing irregular about it.

By the way, 一応 works better for risk mitigation such as 傘を持っていく than risk avoidance such as 家にいる.

Comment: Thank you for the extra advice on how to use 一応 properly!